# Serialize property access exception to json

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a simple class that one of properties is:

```
public TValue Value => IsSuccess
    ? _value
    : throw new InvalidOperationException("The value of a failure result can not be accessed.");
```

So it works like this, when some operation is a success assign value from this operation to property easy. But now I when I do sutch a thig:

```
var result = new Result (someValue) { IsSuccess = false }
var serialized =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result); // of course result type is marked as seriazable
```

So here I am setting such a result to false, and next I want to serilize it, problem is that exception is not serializing and I am getting just thrown exception. What am I missing here?

Comment: That's not (really) a property, though.

Comment: Because you definitely threw the exception.

Comment: It seems you want a discriminated union, which is not (yet) available. You can have workarounds, though. Either write your own implementation or use one of the various libraries, like OneOf (not affiliated). But anyway: If you want the Exception serialized, you cannot throw it. But you can create it without throwing it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486460/how-to-serialize-an-exception-object-in-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358190/how-to-serialise-exception-to-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering whether there isn't a better design for what you're trying to achieve. Namely, it might be better to move the `IsSuccess` check logic into a method so that it doesn't get hit during serialization. But if you really decide to do it this way, you could use a `JsonConverter` to catch and serialize the exception for you:

```cs
public class ValueOrExceptionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, ((dynamic)value).Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new { Value = new { ex.Message } });
        }
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;
}
```

I'm assuming your `Result` class is generic so using this converter would look like this:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(ValueOrExceptionConverter))]
public class Result<TValue>
```

This is all assuming that you're using Newtonsoft.Json. The result of using that converter is something like this:

```json
{"Value":"Message":"The value of a failure result can not be accessed."}}
```

A few notes about the converter code:

- Instead of casting to `dynamic`, you might be better of using an interface or abstract class if you have it. Or if you know exactly which generics you might use for `TValue` then perhaps you can cast even more specifically.
- I've assumed that you don't want to serialize the entire exception. So if you need more than just the `Message` then you can add those properties like so for example: `new { ex.Message, InnerMessage = ex.InnerException.Message }`.
- I've assumed that the `Result` class only has one property, named `Value`. You can add more properties in the same way you can add additional Exception properties.
- I haven't implemented the `ReadJson` because deserializing the exception instead of the value makes that quite tricky. But I'm sure it's not impossible if you need to also deserialize the `Result`.